# How to create a NAS for the office using proxmox and docker container

Tags: docker, server, system-administration, nas, proxmox

I have an old server with 16 cores with two sockets, 16 gigabytes of RAM, which does not have a working hardware raid controller, and it will have 4 hard disks. I need to create a NAS maybe someone who has experience can advise a step-by-step plan on how to create it or an article and whether it is possible to use a proxmox and docker container.

I tried to create a raid 10 through the bios, but the raid controller does not work and the hard drives after creating the raid I had 4 separate disks instead of one. Well, I also did some incomprehensible shit and did not understand anything, I would be glad if you could help me a little.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! We're glad you're here. To get the most out of our community, please take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with our guidelines and expectations. Check out the quick [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the [section on 'on-topic' questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). By following these guidelines, you'll be well-equipped to ask effective questions and receive valuable assistance. Thanks for joining us!